# How to make a Join on query with Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have Comments table where a user can comment on another user like this : 
[image]

And these are constraints : 
[image]

When I use this query :

```
$comments = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()
            ->get('Comments')
            ->find('all');
 $query = $comments
          ->find('all')
          ->contain(['Users']);
```

It retrieves the comment but it applies the **join** only **on** commented_id .
While I want to retrieve The comment object **containing** its two related users one as commentator , the other as commented ,; So how to build the query ?

This is the CommentsTable :

```
class CommentsTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('comments');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'commentator_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'commented_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->scalar('content')
        ->maxLength('content', 255)
        ->requirePresence('content', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('content');

    $validator
        ->integer('score')
        ->requirePresence('score', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('score');

    $validator
        ->dateTime('created_at')
        ->requirePresence('created_at', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('created_at');

    $validator
        ->dateTime('updated_at')
        ->requirePresence('updated_at', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('updated_at');

    return $validator;
}

/**
 * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
 * application integrity.
 *
 * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
 * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
 */
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['commentator_id'], 'Users'));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['commented_id'], 'Users'));

    return $rules;
}
```

}

Comment: Post your associations please from the Comments Table model. Might as well post the Users one as well. Table schema for both would not hurt either.

Comment: @cnizzardini Here I added it :)

Comment: I don't think it matters because you specified the keys, but the convention is user_id instead of commentator_id, and comment_id instead of commented_id. The naming conventions in general here are off. Why not just have a Comments table, a Users table, and a UserComments table and use standard cake conventions. Read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html

Comment: Ok thank you ,; so I have to review my DB structure and naming convention

Comment: @cnizzardini so there is no way to personalize the join on field between tables ?

Comment: There is, but if you are using Cake, you should use the conventions unless their is a good reason not to. If this is a fresh application, I'd follow the conventions.

Comment: You cannot use the same association alias multiple times, they must be unique. See the `className` option in **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chnage your relationships to something like this:

```
$this->belongsTo('Commenters', [
    'className' => 'Users',
    'foreignKey' => 'commentator_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
    'foreignKey' => 'commented_id',
    'joinType' => 'INNER'
]);
```

So then you can contain the two different relationships.

```
$comments = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()
        ->get('Comments')
        ->find('all')
        ->contain(['Commenters', 'Users']);
```

And access them like this:

```
$comment->commenter->name; // Name of the person who commented
$comment->user->name; // Name of the person who was commented on
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what output you what but as per my understanding you can use custom join for the same:

```
$data = $this->Comments->find()
                        ->join([
                          'Users' => [
                                          'table' => 'users',
                                          'type' => 'INNER',
                                          'conditions' => [
                                              'Users.id=Comments.commentator_id',
                                           'OR' => [
                                                'Users.id=Comments.commented_id'
                                                   ]
                                            ] 
                                     ]
                              ]);
```

or you can modify this as per your need.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins

Hope this will help.